# Where's Rebbi Yehudah HaChassid Buried?

Tags: geography, funeral-burial-levaya, biography, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Where, precisely, is Rebbi Yehudah HaChassid - the author of Sefer Chassidim - buried?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93_%28%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%29) he is buried in a cave on Har Hazeisim

> בספרות התקופה מתוארת הלווייתו וקבורתו במערה בהר הזיתים.‏ בספרו תולדות
>   חכמי ירושלים מתאר אריה לייב פרומקין מערה זו, הכוללת כוכים רבים ועליהם
>   כתובות עם שמות העולים הקבורים שם.‏

Comment: http://www.mountofolives.co.il/article.aspx?ID=1053&ref=news&CID=317